# Using url parameters

Tags: php, session, get

i am using php `$_GET` function get the parameter from previous page. Once I retrieve that i have assigned that to a session variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['pId'])) {
    $_SESSION['packageId']=$_GET['pId'];
}

echo $_SESSION['packageId'];

if($_POST['btnSubmit']) {
    $docId=$_SESSION['docId'];
    $appInfoId=$_SESSION['appinfo'];
    $_SESSION['patient_name']=$clName;
    $_SESSION['dob']=$dob;
    $_SESSION['address']=$address;
    $_SESSION['contactno']=$contactNo;
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['packageId']=$packageId;
    header('Location: BookingClientInfo.php');
    exit;
}
```

**Problem:**

When the page is submitted the session is getting clear. But the other sessions used in the page are working fine. Finally I have redirected the page to same URL to check and found that session is getting empty.

Comment: Did you start session before using it ?

Comment: Yes. i have started. i have placed session_start(); this line at the top of the page.

Comment: did you get some output by this///`echo $_SESSION['packageId'];`

Comment: No. It shows the value at the first time the page loads. and when i press submit button, the page reloads and the session doesn't display anything. it looks empty.

Comment: remove this code and check  $_SESSION['packageId']=$packageId;

Comment: have you note your url after submit, is it have `pid` value after submitting for which you are using `$_GET`

Comment: I removed the $_SESSION['packageId']=$packageId; and it is working fine now. Thank you Mahmood Rehman and Dk-Macadamia for your instructions.

Comment: @Prathap Consider writing an Answer to your Question, describing your Solution and marking it as accepted.
This way, the question get's marked as answered and people who land here in the future can more easily find the answer. Also - you get points for that. And who doesn't want points right?